# How to make an NSTextAttachment(image) takes whole line? iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring, nstextattachment

In my UITextView, i just set NSMutableAttributeString an NSTextAttachment which is a UIImage. Though i have set the attachment width to the screen width,but when i tap the image, the input cursor will come into the right of my image.

**but which i want is: 
when insert an image via NSTextAttachment,there should be empty lines at the top and bottom of the image respectively,and the input cursor can only appear in the bottom or the top of the image rather than the left or right.**

[image: WANT]

[image: NOT WANT]

Comment: Maybe by changing manually the selection in `textViewDidChangeSelection:` `UITextViewDelegate` method?

Comment: @Larme thx a lot.   i have try that.  Changing selection can not hit the target.

Comment: I would suggest maybe making the NSTextAttachment bigger (maybe +1 on each side) than the UITextView, that might prevent the cursor from appearing next to it.